# Grafana transformations: calculate percentage in the table panel

Tags: grafana, opentsdb, grafana-api

i am using grafana-v7.3.6 on ubuntu.
i basically have a timeseries with different versions as tags. I want to create a table with each version and its percentage of the total value. I am using opentsdb-v2.4 as my datasource.

example:

```
time,      metric,                 value
...      result{version = 1},      10
...      result{version = 2},      5
...      result{version = 1},      5
...      result{version = 3},      2
...      result{version = 1},      2
...      result{version = 3},      5
...      result{version = 2},      5
...      result{version = 1},      3
...      result{version = 2},      0
...      result{version = 3},      3
```

using series to rows transformations: i was able to get the following:

```
metric,                   value
result{version = 1},      20
result{version = 2},      10
result{version = 3},      10
```

What i would like is the following:

```
metric,                   value
result{version = 1},      50%
result{version = 2},      25%
result{version = 3},      25%
```

how can i achieve this?
any pointers/suggestions would be really appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Hay, did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the query you're using with the following:

```
your-query/scalar(sum(your-query))
```

Comment: can you please elaborate.. do you mean to do this in opentsdb expressions? grafana does not support expressions yet.